# Gatsby createPages with single JSON file doesn't refresh data changes

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to create pages dynamically from a single JSON file with Gatsby, without using GraphQL.

The `works.json` file looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Client Name",
    "slug": "client-name",
    "abstract": "some description in here",
    "src": "img01",
    ...
  },
  {
    "title": "Client Name 2",
    "slug": "client-name-2",
    "abstract": "some description in here",
    "src": "img02",
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

Then I created the proper action on `gatsby-node.js` like this:

```js
exports.createPages = ({ actions: { createPage } }) => {
  const projects = require("./src/data/works.json")
  projects.forEach(project => {
    createPage({
      path: `/project/${project.id}`,
      component: require.resolve("./src/templates/project.js"),
      context: project,
    })
  })
}
```

Everything is working pretty well, and all the data gets displayed accordingly to how I designed the template **except that if I change any string in `works.json`, nothing changes on the displayed page.**

To see the changes I have to kill the `gatsby development server`, clear the `.cache` with `gatsby clean` and restart `gatsby develop`.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?
It seems strange to me that `createPages` does not work dynamically when the data is changed since Gatsby detects the change and refresh itself...

I'm using `gatsby: 2.25.3`

Answer (score 0):

Gatsby will refresh the changes when you use GraphQL as it can then track the changes you're making. It's the intended usage of Gatsby and there are rarely reasons to not use GraphQL.

By passing `project` through `context` your users will download all the `project` data on the page visit even though you might only use parts of it.

You can read more about the disadvantages here: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages#trade-offs-of-querying-for-all-fields-in-the-context-object-of-gatsby-nodejs

Comment: I can’t see a reason for no-refresh thou. Even if the process is probably longer, why I can’t see my changes on dev mode? I have to change my context? I have to refactor some code?

Answer (score 0):

All changes in the data sources require to stop and relaunch the server because Gatsby needs to parse and treat the data again (to create its nodes again), the static data is generated in each `build` or `develop` process so you'll need to run it every time.

However, you thing that may work for you is using [Refreshing Content](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/refreshing-content/) feature. Gatsby exposes an environment variable called `ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT` that once set, by changing your develop command to:

```
"develop": "ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT=true gatsby develop",
```

When the variable is set to `true`, it will expose a `/__refresh` webhook that can receive `POST` requests to refresh the sourced content. This exposed webhook can be triggered whenever remote data changes by:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/__refresh
```

You can automate it within a button or whatever implementation you wish.